# Pandas MultiIndex DataFrame outer product

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have the two MultiIndex DataFrames

[image: df1]

and

[image: df2]

and want to multiply the two in such a way that I produce:

[image]

How can I do this generally? Note that there may be an arbitrary number of `foo` variables, each of which may contain arbitrary numbers of `bar` variables.

Below is code to reproduce the two original DataFrames, `df_1` and `df_2`:

```
vals_1 =  pd.np.random.rand(2, 4) * 100
tuples_1 = [('A', 'P'), ('A', 'Q'), ('B', 'R'), ('B', 'S')]
idx_1 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_1, names=['foo', 'bar'])
df_1 = pd.DataFrame(vals_1, columns=idx_1)

rs = pd.np.random.rand(2, 1)
rs2 = pd.np.random.rand(2, 1)
vals_2 = pd.np.concatenate([rs, 1 - rs, rs2, 1 - rs2], axis=1)
tuples_2 = [('A', 'spam'), ('A', 'eggs'), ('B', 'spam'), ('B', 'eggs')]
idx_2 = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(tuples_2, names=['foo', 'qux'])
df_2 = pd.DataFrame(vals_2, columns=idx_2)
```

Comment: First of all, please provide dataframes in a form where I don't have to type them in by hand, please.

Comment: Added code to reproduce in the edit

Answer (score 0):

One unsatisfactory approach I've come up with involves `pd.melt` and `pd.pivot_table`:

```
melted_1 = pd.melt(df_1.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'], value_name='val')
melted_2 = pd.melt(df_2.reset_index(), id_vars=['index'], value_name='val')
merged = pd.merge(melted_1, melted_2, on=['index', 'foo'], how='left')
merged['val'] = merged['val_x'] * merged['val_y']
merged = merged.drop(['val_x', 'val_y'], axis=1)
df_3 = pd.pivot_table(merged, values='val', index='index', columns=['foo', 'bar', 'qux'])
```

Ideally there would be a less roundabout solution that retains the MultiIndex structure throughout.